# New Email Verification/No Access To Old Email Account

Tags: php

I have a program for a client I'm building and I've a system that initially verify their email by sending them a hash and if they send a correct hash they get entered. What I'm wanting to do is have users be able to update their email to a new email address and I'm wondering what is the best way to do it.

What I've thought of doing is:

User completes form for email change and a entry goes into the database with new email address and creates a hash (w/ timeout) and sends them a email with the hash to the old email address.

But that leads me to what to do with users that don't have access to their old email address. Should I have the admin manually update their email address by sending the admin a email by having a 'cannot access your old email address' checkbox with a area for the user to add a message for the admin. Then the admin sends a email with a hash for that user.

OR is there some other way I should accomplish this task.

**EDIT:** I think it might be best to add a 'whats your favorite __' question W/ answer into the database for thoes certain cases.

Comment: About your edit and your comment below my answer: What are you going to do if the account is hacked and the hacker changes that question before changing the password? Get a good authentication system and stick with it.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new to this site. Anyways do most places you can only answer them once and you have to remember/write them down.

Comment: I don't know of any site where you cannot change everything except perhaps your username. You can give it a try of course...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you send the message to the old address?

Obviously you need to keep track of both addresses until the new one is confirmed, but if the user is authenticated, you should just send the change-mail message to the new address.

Comment: What if someone hijacked their account and then they can change their email address without notifying the old email that they approved/did this action. Like most places I've seen do (I think).

Comment: @Class True, but you have an authentication mechanism in place so if a user want to change his / her e-mail address you should be able to rely on that authentication mechanism. There is no way you can cover all situations if a users account has been hacked and trying to catch some possible situations just leads to a false sense of security.

Comment: What about thoes 'whats your favorite __' sort of questions when they register and use it in this situation (along with others).